# issue with creating JWT Token

Tags: javascript, axios, jwt, token, bearer-token

when I give generated token(I copy paste the token which is print) directly to header field like a first code snippet its work fine and I can get data from that server

```
   //Create Token
   const secretKey = `${process.env.SECRETKEY}`;
   const header = { typ: 'JWT', alg: 'HS256' };
   const payload = {
     timestamp: timestamp,
     partnerId: process.env.PARTNERID,
     reqid: randomNumber,
   };
   let token = jwt.sign(payload, secretKey, { header });
   console.log(token);
  
   //Call PaySprint Server
   const makereq = async () => {
     try {
       const headerz = {
        "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE2ODg2NDA2MjIsInBhcnRuZXJJZCI6IkNPUlAwMDAwMSIsInJlcWlkIjoiNzgwMzg0MTUxNiIsImlhdCI6MTY4ODY0MDYyMn0.dJA4a6Q6CwcsrPjrDPMs2M5SlgtCXkGna5C8CAeAoz0",
        "authorisedkey": process.env.AUTHORISEDKEY
       };

       console.log(typeof headerz.token);
       
       const callPaysprint = await axios.post(url, body, { headers: headerz });
       return {
         data: callPaysprint.data,
         url: url,
         request: body,
       };
     } catch (error) {
       throw error;
     }
   };
   const result = await makereq();
```

but instead I give the token variable to the header like below its give a errorcode 500

```
   //Create Token
   const secretKey = `${process.env.SECRETKEY}`;
   const header = { typ: 'JWT', alg: 'HS256' };
   const payload = {
     timestamp: timestamp,
     partnerId: process.env.PARTNERID,
     reqid: randomNumber,
   };
   let token = jwt.sign(payload, secretKey, { header });
   console.log(token);
  
   //Call PaySprint Server
   const makereq = async () => {
     try {
       const headerz = {
        "token": token,
        "authorisedkey": process.env.AUTHORISEDKEY
       };

       console.log(typeof headerz.token);
       
       const callPaysprint = await axios.post(url, body, { headers: headerz });
       return {
         data: callPaysprint.data,
         url: url,
         request: body,
       };
     } catch (error) {
       throw error;
     }
   };
   const result = await makereq();
```

is there any problem with creating token or something

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the server side? If so, can you show us them?

Comment: Does it print console.log(token); type of string ?

Comment: try printing the token inside of that function - you will likely see that it is undefined. you need to pass that token into your funciton. as it is an arrow function it has its own scope.